# Cloud Functions for Firebase "Create" Trigger - multiple collections

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I created 3 Collection on root i.e Brand, Pack & Item in the same project. Can I keep "create" functions against each collection same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Just create three different wildcard functions with the onCreate trigger

```
exports.BrandFunction = functions.firestore
  .document('brands/{brandId}')
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
//Function doesnt need to be async unless you use await in the body
//YOUR CODE HERE 
});

exports.PackFunction = functions.firestore
  .document('packs/{packId}')
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
//YOUR CODE HERE 
});

exports.ItemFunction = functions.firestore
  .document('items/{itemId}')
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
//YOUR CODE HERE 
});
```

Comment: Thanks Renaud Tarnec & barbecu for your quick response, I was missing somehow this.. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you may use as many wildcards as you like to substitute explicit **collection** or **document** IDs, for example:

```
exports.multiCollections = functions.firestore
    .document('{collectionId}/{docId}')
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
        console.log(context.params.collectionId);
        console.log(context.params.docId);

        return null;

    });
```

---

See the doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#wildcards-parameters